# Exponents of factor groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to show that

$$\exp(G/M) | \exp(G/N)\cdot\exp(N/M)$$

where $G$ is a group and $N,M$ are normal subgroups such $M\leq N$ .

I would be grateful for any hint or advice.

Thank you!

EDIT: I know that $\exp(G) | \exp(N)\cdot\exp(G/N)$, but I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: It is enough to show that for every $g\in G$, $g^{rs}\in M$, where $r=\mathrm{exp}(G/N)$ and $s=\mathrm{exp}(N/M)$. To do that, show that in general, if $K\triangleleft G$ and $k=\mathrm{exp}(G/K)$, then $g^k\in K$ for all $g\in G$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin For $g\in G$ it is: $(gK)^k=g^k K = K$ And that is equivalent ot saying $g^k \in K$. But why is it enough to show that?

Comment: Because the exponent of a group divides any number $n$ such that $x^n$ is trivial for all $x$. If for every $g\in G$, $g^{rs}\in M$, then for every $gM\in G/M$, $(gM)^{rs} = eM$, which means the exponent of $G/M$ divides $rs$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you very much!